# Technical review failed on module submission

Tags: magento2, php

I am new in **Magento** and have a project for building a custom shipping carrier module with PHP and Magento, in which I have. Now when going for submission in the Technical Review section, I always get an error in the Manual QA part. I am running using **PHP 7.4** on my machine and installed **magento 2.4.1**. From their side (Logs) after installing the module, it doesn't appear in the Admin dashboard under the delivery methods tabs, but on my side, it is working just fine. I have converted the module into a composer installer: https://packagist.org/packages/droppa-2020/droppashipping and still gets rejected. Please see the report below.

```
{
    "tool":"manual_qa",
    "status":"FAIL",
    "reports":{
        "tool":"manual_qa",
        "vendor":"droppa-2020",
        "extension":"droppashipping",
        "version":"1.0.0",
        "status":"FAIL",
        "date":"2021-05-30 15:07:16",
        "details":{
            "reasons":[
                
            ],
            "message":"<p>Test Environment Used:<\/p>\n<p>Magento Ver. 2.4.2 Community Edition (PHP 7.4.13)<\/p>\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n<p>Reason for failure:<\/p>\n<p>Unable to configure the extension as per User Guide - Unable to find Droppa Shipping module.<\/p>\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n<p>Steps:<\/p>\n<ol>\n<li>Login to Admin<\/li>\n<li>Navigate to Stores &gt; Configuration<\/li>\n<li>Go to Sales &gt; Delivery Methods<\/li>\n<\/ol>\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n<p>Expected Result: There must be Droppa Shipping module under Delivery Methods<\/p>\n<p>Actual result: Droppa Shipping module is missing under Delivery Methods<\/p>\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n<p>Tested browser: Google Chrome Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)<\/p>\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n<p>Video: Click <a href=\"https:\/\/documentcloud.adobe.com\/link\/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:852b7e1d-ac52-4bbe-901d-9d8d8ed0a252\" target=\"_blank\">here<\/a><\/p>\n<p>Logs: No<\/p>\n<p>Screenshot: Attached<\/p>\n<p>Other attachments, notes, etc.: No<\/p>",
            "attachment":"https:\/\/mp-static.magento.com\/user\/attachments\/e2\/c0\/e2c0dcfcff485a7e35b0b881a1e39fbf8435d031\/prv\/77\/09\/77099e1bc34ff5540733c3ef7696e326\/d13327409c253de37f1e31e2760cb7b5.zip"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have also added my composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "droppa-2020/droppashipping",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "description": "Custom Droppa Shipping Module",
    "keywords": [
        "Magento 2",
        "Magento 2 Courier",
        "Magento 2 Shipping",
        "Courier",
        "Magento 2 extension free"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0||~7.4.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Droppa\\DroppaShipping\\": ""
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jack Manamela",
            "email": "jackm@droppa.co.za",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "<work_email_goes_here>"
    },
    "archive": {
        "name": "../DroppaShipping",
        "skip-dev": false
    },
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Where could I be going wrong? Kindly assist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: registration.php looks a little odd.

Comment: @jiheison - Odd, how so? This is the code in the registration file.

`
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

$name = implode('_', array_map(
    function ($part) {
        return implode(array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $part)));
    },
    array_slice(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __DIR__), -2, 2)
));

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, $name, __DIR__);
`

Comment: It just doesn't look like the registration.php file in any module I have looked at or created. E.g. https://packagist.org/packages/mailchimp/mc-magento & https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/blob/develop-2.3/registration.php, which follows https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/component-registration.html#register-modules